# Explicit constants for Bézout-style theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I was recently reading a paper of Yang, [Generalizations of Joints Problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.08525), where I came across the following proposition (Proposition 6 in the paper):

Suppose $V_1$ and $V_2$ are $k_1$-dimensional and $k_2$-dimensional (irreducible) algebraic varieties of degrees $D_1$ and $D_2$ respectively in $\mathbb C^n$.

If $V_1$ is not contained in $V_2$, then their intersection $V_1 \cap V_2$ will be an algebraic set containing $O_{D_{1}, D_{2},n}(1)$ varieties whose dimension is strictly smaller than $k_1$ and degree at most $O_{D_{1}, D_{2},n}(1)$.

I am looking for results that give a more explicit bound for the number of varieties contained in $V_1 \cap V_2$. In particular, I'm interested in results on the explicit dependence on $D_1$ and $D_2$. The current case of the problem I'm working on is related to a 4 and 2 dimensional pair of varieties, so even a result in this special case would be much appreciated.